# Unity3D Map Diablo2 - Style

Tags: dictionary, unity-game-engine, styles, textures, opacity

first of all thanks for read and sorry for my english.

I want make a Diablo 2 Style Map for my school project.
Basically is a map with opacity.

I have my Rendered Map Texture but I don't know how set Alpha/Opacity

[image]

Thanks!!

Edit - More Information

I have a camera attached to a Render Texture and I draw it as Texture into game

[image]

```
if(Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
{   
    Graphics.DrawTexture (new Rect (300, 300, 256, 256), MiniMapTexture, MiniMapMaterial);
}
```

And I want set Opacity to this texture.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't exactly post enough information about what you're doing for anyone to really determine how to properly help you, but you're probably looking for [material.SetColor](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html).

You can access the material on a GameObject by way of the renderer. For instance, if you wanted to set the opacity of your game object to 50%:

```
var color = renderer.material.GetColor("_Color");
color.a = 0.5f;
renderer.material.SetColor("_Color", color);
```

Just tested this on a sprite quickly and it worked. But if you want further explanation, you'll need to expand on your question.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried your solution and doesn't work, basically I don't have Renderer to modify, I will put more information